# Problem with "numcases"

Tags: math-mode, equations, labels, cases

Please I need to create a formula with specific emplacements, something like
[image]

I used \usepackage{cases} with the  "numcases" environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{numcases}{}
    \label{e2.1} ..........\\
    \label{e2.2}\quad........\\
    \qquad.........\\
    \label{e2.3}\quad.........\\
    \qquad..........\\
    \qquad.........\\
    \label{e2.4}\quad.........\\
    \qquad.........
    \end{numcases}

\end{document}
```

I would like to get just three equations (2.1)-(2.3) where (2.1) is centered between the 2nd and 3rd lines, (2.2) centered between the 5th and 6th lines and finally (2.3) instead of (2.8) in the figure.

Comment: So, a line in the cases should be made with `aligned`, for example, to group then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}
\newcommand{\mydots}{\dots\dots}
\begin{document}
\begin{numcases}{}
\mydots\\
\begin{aligned}
&\quad\mydots\\
&\qquad\mydots
\end{aligned}\\
\quad\mydots\\
\begin{aligned}
&\qquad\mydots\\
&\qquad\mydots
\end{aligned}\\
\quad\mydots
\end{numcases}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I have to add "quad" to get my formula? there is a simplet method to get exactly the result of the figure ?

Comment: @M.A Do you want a fixed width dots?

Comment: Yes please, but (1) and (3)  with no numbers.

Comment: @M.A, to remove a number, simply use `\nonumber` before \\.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `empheq` that's much more powerful than `cases`.

Your requirement about equation numbers can be achieved by nesting `aligned`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
& \mathstrut ..........
\label{e2.1}
\\
&\begin{aligned}
  &\quad.........\\
  &\qquad.........
\end{aligned}
\label{e2.2}
\\
&\begin{aligned}
  &\quad..........\\
  &\qquad..........\\
  &\qquad..........
\end{aligned}
\label{e2.3}
\\
&\begin{aligned}
  &\quad.........\\
  &\qquad.........
\end{aligned}
\label{e2.4}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The "empheq" environment don't give numbers to the equations.

Comment: @M.A You asked that: "I would like to get just three equations (2.1)-(2.3) where (2.1) is centered between the 2nd and 3rd lines, (2.2) centered between the 5th and 6th lines and finally (2.3) instead of (2.8) in the figure."

Comment: Yes, but  when I use your code, I get  just the left lbrace and the points without any numbers in the right-hand side.

Comment: @M.A They are in the image, produced with the very same code posted.